Need to read old xls file instead with xlsx with st_read()
I want to know if it is possible to enable/add the Gdal driver to read Excel files that are in the old xls format. We are consuming data that is still being produced in the xls format.
I see on Gdal that there is a xls driver which has a dependency on libfreexl.
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/xls.html
Is there a way to enable the Gdal xls driver in the spatial extension?
CREATE TABLE step1 AS SELECT * FROM st_read('./step1/Old_Excel_Format.xls', layer = 'General');

** Update **
I see in the code that there is a call to OGRRegisterAllInternal() and it does not seem that you are able to load additional Gdal drivers, I am not sure if the xls driver is part of the Gdal build that is loaded by DuckDB.
https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb_spatial/blob/main/spatial/src/spatial/gdal/module.cpp


There is no such thing as XLS file, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247  which has, at least, two different names for XLS files ("The Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Binary file format (BIFF8)" and "The Excel 5.0/95 Binary file format (BIFF5)" )

Sorry Luuk, I agree with you. I should have phrased the question differently.
The question is, if it is possible  to enable the Gdal xls driver in DuckDB as part of the spatial extension.

Another way might be to use [ImportExcel]. This Powershell has a function named ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx, which can convert XLS files to XLSX.
